# VueJS (Typescript) - SVGs not rendering

Tags: typescript, vue.js

So I have a weird problem that should've be straight forward.
if using vue with js as cdn.... than this works perfectly (as it does in angular or anywhere else)

```
<img src="/assets/images/icons/myicoin.svg>
```

but oddly if I do it via webpack (and typescript), it does not work... when accessing the svg directly

> http://localhost:8080/assets/images/icons/myicoin.svg

it tries to render the app instead of the icon

I tried using vue-svg-loader

but it feels waaaaay over engineered and it does not work as I want it...

so any idea how to tell webpack to leave SVGs alone abd treat it as any other image resource?

Odly enough if I enclude it as an external resource (different domain) it works completely fine

Comment: You need to use a relative URL in order to get webpack to resolve the asset: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html#asset-resolving-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, for those who don't know

**DON'T** PUT static assets like photos (including) SVGs into `src/assets` folder, put them into `public/assets`

**all static assets** should be put in the **public** folder, which on build, is just copied over!

Hope will help someone!

Comment: So you have three folders in your project root? (public, src, build) ?

Comment: no build for me.... public and src.... the public is suppossed to be static... and when I build I get the combination of the two into the dist forlder